# Gstreamer streaming over udp

Tags: android, eclipse, gstreamer, decoder

I have ported gstreamer to android and I am using eclipse (juno). Now, I am able to receive audio stream over udp, but when I try to give any video clip as input, I get the error, **amcaudiodec-omxgoogleacdecoder - Gstreamer encountered an internal library error.** I dont know how to solve this decoder problem. Any idea regarding what might the error could be?

Also, I wanted to know what is the difference between the plugins playbin and playbin2. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Don't know anything about the error you encounter, but as for playbin/playbin2, I think that the only thing to know is that playbin is deprecated and should never be used. Is there a specific reason you're asking about the difference?

Comment: You need to look into Android log for more details. You're not the only one with `androidmedia` problems, though.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add "androidmedia" plugin to the Android.mk file, as per plugins.mk file.

I suspect, as you have not included this in your Android.mk, playbin is trying to internally invoke this element, hence the lob

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but your problem may be that you cannot use a pipeline meant to play audio files to play a video file.

Video files are usually in a container format such as .avi, .mkv which need to be **demultiplexed** into separate audio and video streams. Once you have this audio stream you can apply your audio pipeline to play audio.

Here's an example pipeline to play audio while ignoring video: (Try it on the command line)

```
gst-launch filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux  ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```